# angular2 with MVC6, browsers can't access scripts inside of node_modules

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Trying to use Angular2 with TypeScript, which means importing from `node_modules` folder. I have `node_modules` with built-in `npm` installed in their default status, the main project folder, but referencing any `.js` scripts in any given web page will result in 404 not found error in browser. Tried removing `node_modules`, still didn't work. So after a lot of tries and failures, it's surprising that even in a brand new ASP.NET 5 project which has everything pre-installed and configured, browser can't access referenced `.js` scripts in `node_modules` nor import types (it makes ajax calls for those scripts referenced in TypeScript files, and fails).

Apparently with DNX and ASP.NET 5, there is an exclusion of `node_modules` in `tsconfig.json` and `project.json` along with the `wwwroot`. So I tried to remove that option, then got this error at compile time:

"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Interestingly, I can import the types and modules in `.ts` files and it works fine in designer, meaning it recognizes the imported types. However at run-time, I still get 404s for those imported modules and main Angular2 scripts from `node_modules`. Any suggestions are welcomed as i'm out of options.

**Environment**

1. Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 1
2. DNX 4.6.1 and 5.0
3. Chrome version 49, Firefox version 43, IE version 11

**Update**

This is the folder structure:

```
MyWebApplication
    project.json
    package.json
    ...
    -node_modules
    ...
    -wwwroot
    ...
       -ts
         -pages
              orders-page.ts
       tsconfig.json
       typings.json
    ...
```

Here are the screenshots from _Layout.cshtml, orders-page.ts and its error, tsconfig.json and project.json:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that you have to have a `module` element in your `tsconfig.json` and set it's value to `system`, this is already part of angular2 quickstart. However, you also need to add another element named `moduleResolution` to the `tsconfig.json` and set it's value to "node". This is just Typescript compiler additions. See [Typescript module resolution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039)

Additionally, in regards to `node_modules` not receiving http request, it's not possible to do that and as previous posts suggested you would need a gulp task to move all of your generated `.js` files inside of `wwwroot` in order for them to be visible. This needs to follow the same folder structure as your Typescript folders. So if you have `/ts/mytest.ts` you'll need the same structure under `wwwroot`, for example `wwwroot/myFolder/ts/mytest.ts` but watchout for SystemJS configuration as it has to point to `myFolder`. If you already placed the Typscript folder under the `wwwroot`, i suggest to put it under the root of your project and just move the generated `.js` files.

Answer (score 5):

You could just copy all the referenced files to wwwroot or better yet create a gulp/grunt task to do it. As for the file/directory length problem - this is fixed in later versions of NPM, however Visual Studio uses an earlier one by default, but you can change it :[here is how](http://jameschambers.com/2015/09/upgrading-npm-in-visual-studio-2015/). I recommend the second option, works perfect for me. After doing this just delete node_modules and restore NPM packages, you shouldn't get that error again.

Update : 
You don't need to reference any typescpript files, all you need is this in the html where you use angular:

```
    <script src="/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/system.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                appJs: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Where you replace "appJs" with the folder your .ts are transpiled to .js files
After that importing angular modules in your typescript will work fine, for example :

> import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

will be imported from node_modules/angular2/cote.ts without you having to reference it anywhere. This is a gulp task that copies the required files for you from "node_modules" to "wwwroot/js":

```
var gulp = require('gulp');


gulp.task('libs', function () {
    return gulp.src([
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.*.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.*.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.*.js*',
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/*.*',
      'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/js/'));
});
```

Comment: First, how would you know the referenced files? going around potentially hundreds of typescript files and figuring out the 'imports' is not practical in large applications. Second, none of those fixes actually worked as i tried them. I still have to exclude the 'node_modules' and i suspect that means no http requests can be made to that folder.

Comment: Update: that's exactly what i did first. Doesn't work. I get the same error in designer and can't build the project. Says "module ... not found"

Comment: Can you post your code: html where you include the scripts, .ts where you get the error, and tsconfig.json? Also check your typescript version and try updating it from here : [UpdateLink](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593)

Comment: Check screenshots.

Comment: You need the files in specific order, try changing the order to match mine. You need "Rx.js", not "rx.js", big "R". In the system.config packages you need to provide the folder of your typescript transpiled files, not angular, which has to be in "wwwroot". For example if it's in wwwroot/app, you just need to provide "app" .

Comment: Tried all of that already, none worked. I'm not asking a question if i haven't tried at least 10 different ways. Just to address your last comment, i've tried setting it to 'app', but at run-time INSIDE of browser i'll get 404 not found. Reason being what you put in '.ts' imports, that url for import, has to match an exact .js file in exact same location when ran inside of browser.

Comment: In what folder is your angular app?  You also need to remove wwwroot from the exclude in tsconfig.

Comment: Ok I see it's in wwwroot/ts. So lets try the following : 1. Do everything in my previous post, 2. Remove wwwroot from the exclude in tsconfig. 3. In System.Config packages add ts instead of nodu_modules. : ` System.config({
            packages: {
                ts: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });`